# Lost on AJAX to .ASP file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a need to automate data collection for users who visit specific pages of my site.  To do this, I'm querying the LDAP.  The LDAP query works just fine when I double click on the file locally (`.vbs`).  However, when I double click on it while it's on the server, it doesn't work (as would be expected).  However, I'm as new as new can get to writing VBScript.

After reading a few articles I modified the code and changed the extension to `.asp`.  I ended up with this:

```
<%
    On Error Resume Next

    'Create the Array that will be passed
    Dim employee(7)

    'Employee System Related Info
    Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")

    employee(0) = objSysInfo.SiteName

    'Employee specific information
    strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
    Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)

    employee(1) = objUser.sAMAccountName
    employee(2) = objUser.givenName
    employee(3) = objUser.sn
    employee(4) = objUser.displayName
    employee(5) = objUser.telephoneNumber
    employee(6) = objUser.title

    Return employee
%>
```

In the JavaScript function which would call this `.asp` file via ajax, I am able to get the employee number which *I think* could be received by the `.asp` file and do the rest of the query.... However, I'm not even sure if I'm returning everything correctly in the `VBScript`.  Furthermore, I'm not even sure if I should be using a `GET` or `POST` AJAX call.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Updated 03/22/2017 at 10AM CDT**

I've finally gotten back to the office and tried to play around.  I'm still a little lost.  I've made some updates to the code below you'll see the javascript and the VBScript

FIRST the JavaScript:

```
var employee = {};
function getEmp() {
var ldapUserName = ADSystem.UserName;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: ldapUserName,
    url: "https://here.is.my/url.asp", 
    success: $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function(responseText) {
                employee = responseText;
             },
             error: function() {
                    alert("No Data Received");
             }
        }),
    error: function() {
            alert("Connection Failed");
        }
    });
}
```

Now here is the updated VBScript based on a few things I read and the suggestions from here:

```
<%
Public Function empDemo(username)

On Error Resume Next
'Create the Array that will be passed
Dim employee(7)

'Employee System Related Info
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
employee(0) = objSysInfo.SiteName

'Employee specific information
strUser = objSysInfo.username
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)

employee(1) = objUser.sAMAccountName
employee(2) = objUser.givenName
employee(3) = objUser.sn
employee(4) = objUser.displayName
employee(5) = objUser.telephoneNumber
employee(6) = objUser.title

response.write "{ site: " & employee(0) & "," 
        & "empNum: " & employee(1) & "," 
        & "empFName: " & employee(2) & "," 
        & "empLName: " & employee(3) & ","
        & "empFullName: " & employee(4) & ","
        & "empExt: " & employee(5) & ","
        & "empTitle: " & employee(6) & "}"

End Function
%>
```

Currently, I'm getting the alert stating "No Data Received".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Return` us not a valid statement in VBScript but as you have `On Error Resume Next` statement it will fail silently and be skipped. If you want to get to the bottom of what is wrong with the code, comment out the `On Error Resume Next` line.

Comment: If you want to return your Array as a JSON structure, I'd recommend looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42417686/692942). While it deals with a recordset the same library it links to allows you to pass Arrays. See the [examples](https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON).

Comment: Can you write an example of the data format and value you need to receive from the ajax call?

Comment: I just updated the original question.  Please review.  I either solved a lot of the misunderstanding I had before... or showed more of my misunderstanding.  I hope it's the earlier...

Comment: I gave up on this question and started a new one since I've learned quite a bit more. the new question can be [seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984834/use-aspx-file-as-a-server-side-code-to-be-called-via-ajax-by-html-javascript-cl)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "return Employee", have you tried:

```
response.write employee
```

or maybe

```
response.write employee.sAMAccountName
```

Is this VB6? Not sure what libraries are available in classic asp, so you might have to manually write the data in JSON form... i.e...

```
response.write "{ name: " & employee.sAMAccountName & "}"
```

Comment: I'm about to leave for the day, but I will be happy to try that when I get to work tomorrow.  It just occurred to me that I need to do a POST with a GET function in the success part of the AJAX during the VB.  In the POST, I need to pass some data that I can obtain from the user directly.

However, your response, will definitely h elp me in terms of receiving the data back and working with it in the JS.

Comment: Classic ASP uses VBScript not VB6, while similar there are differences. They are taking a Array and populating with the results of an LDAP query via ADSI.

Comment: I just updated the original question. Please review. I either solved a lot of the misunderstanding I had before... or showed more of my misunderstanding. I hope it's the earlier...

Comment: It appears you created a function, but did you call it? If you don't call your function, then it is never executed. if you place "empDemo username" before the function, then it should be executed. I believe you should be able to open the URL in a web browser to verify you are getting data.

Comment: sweet!  Thank you @birwin.  I just tested it with data that I would like to pass from the client to this .vbs file (I should use a .vbs file as opposed to .asp right?)... and it worked.  However, that opens up the other question that I'm *mostly* confused about:  how do I pass the data from client side to server side and **know** that the data will be received by the function.  Before responding, I read through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865269/jquery-ajax-and-vbscript-cant-get-values-in-vbscript-variables-when-using-pos and I'm still confused because I'm gathering all my data from JS

Comment: I just read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342465/how-do-you-pass-a-javascript-variable-as-an-argument-to-a-vbscript-function-in

so, I can just load this file in the HTML... even though it's server-side and it will still perform all the work?  I'm going to go test this...

Comment: nevermind... I see that is if you have vbscript and js on the same page.

Comment: On the client, you have to use an AJAX call to get the data from the server... What framework are you using on the client? Angular? jQuery? Straight Javascript? Other?

Comment: jquery/JS hybrid.  I'm having it added to a function that does a few other things... however, the function is called on-load.

Comment: $.get( "yoururl.asp", function(data) {
  alert( "success" );
})

Comment: I know how to do the ajax.  What I don't know is how to receive the data  that I'm sending from the ajax into the function in the VBScript.

Comment: request("paramname")... So if your URL looks like so: http://myserver/page.asp?name=fred, request("name") would be "fred"

Comment: I see what you're referring to.  I'm still having some trouble.  But I'll try to get it sorted out before I ask another question.

Comment: I gave up on this question and started a new one since I've learned quite a bit more.  the new q uestion can be [seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984834/use-aspx-file-as-a-server-side-code-to-be-called-via-ajax-by-html-javascript-cl)